# SharePoint Workflow Not Rendering Word Document if Text Contains Special Characters

Tags: sharepoint-online

(SharePoint Online) Using the standard SharePoint workflow (no SharePoint Designer) that renders data from a SharePoint form to a Word Document works properly, except when a field on the SharePoint form contains text that includes "special characters" like -, /, etc.  Is there a way to write the workflow that will somehow overlook the special characters and successfully render the Word document?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about “render the Word document”? Do you mean updating the document with data retrieved by workflow? Also are you using SharePoint 2010 workflow?

Comment: We are using SharePoint Online 2016 workflow features.  And, the Word document is created from data retrieved by the workflow.  Users are entering data into a SharePoint online form.  Thanks, so much.

Comment: I assume you mean the SharePoint 2013 platform workflow. I’m not quite sure how it works, but if you can find a way to use rich text format in the workflow, then the special characters should render successfully.